# I am looking for an easy to use graphical data recovery program

Tags: software-recommendation, data-recovery

I am looking for a easy to use, easy to install, data recovery application (like recuva)
I have tried test disk and haven't figured out how to it.

So my question is. does anyone know of a easy to use (including easy to install) data recovery application for ubuntu.

Comment: Have a look here for starters: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery (and datarecovery is not easy by nature ;) )

Comment: yah. I did try that too...I am preferably looking for a NON command line way...if posible...but thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Autopsy Forensic Browser](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+package/autopsy) (Available in the software center) is a graphical interface to [SleuthKit](http://www.sleuthkit.org/autopsy/).

[image: images1]